# Opening Windows Powershell through c#

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I'm trying to open Powershell through C# code and ultimately the goal is to also write command lines through c# (without using a powershell skript).

I did some reasearch and came up with this code snippet, but for some reason it just doesn't open Powershell. What do I need to change about the code for Powershell to open?

```
//Opening Powershell
private void Execute()
{
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe",
RedirectStandardOutput = true,
RedirectStandardError = true,
UseShellExecute = false,
CreateNoWindow = true,
};
Process pro = Process.Start(startInfo);
pro.WaitForExit();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
pro.Close();
}
```

Comment: There are at least two typos that a compiler would complain about. Can you post your real code and explain what "does not open" means? Do you get errors?

Comment: @nvoigt excuse the typos - I corrected them. I do not get any errors. I'm trying to open the powershell console.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen? Can you describe that in plain English?

Comment: You need to post what you expect to happen here. For instance, your statement "open the powershell console" *could* mean that you want a Window to appear. However, you've said "CreateNoWindow = true", you're attempting to redirect all output. So to me this seems like a conflict. As such, you must describe exactly what you expect to happen here.

Comment: I think he want's to open the powershell console. Remove this `CreateNoWindow = true,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with this. Maybe there are some other ways to do it, but this works as well. Since you want some initial setup I think you need to use [EnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_EnvironmentVariables) and if you do that you also need to add

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

so one working example would be

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenPowerShell(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe");
    }

    static void OpenPowerShell(string path)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("RedirectStandardOutput", "true");
        startInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("RedirectStandardError", "true");
        startInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("UseShellExecute", "false");
        startInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("CreateNoWindow", "true");
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

Or if you are OK with another window just:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenPowerShell(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe");
    }

    static void OpenPowerShell(string path)
    {
        Process.Start(path);
    }
```

Comment: Your first example didn't work for some reasen, the powershell console didn't open. The second example did work though. But only starting powershell won't allow me to write commands in it through c#, right? Because I never set RedirectStandardOutput true?

Comment: @as19aux To be honest, I haven't played with this a lot. I just got interested in the question so I tried it myself. My understanding is that either - You can open a new powershell window by just running `Process.start(path)` or you can pass the variables and use the command prompt as a powershell shell while it is running. Not sure this is entirely correct though.